# jqGrid - how to reset search options?

Tags: jquery, search, jqgrid

Using jqGrid multiple [searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3asinge_searching) how can you programatically "clear" the search options?

The "clear" should ensure no `filters` are being sent to the server and that the GUI search box does not contain any search criteria..

We are currently calling `trigger("reloadGrid")`.  We'd like to call a `clearSearchCrieria()` type method before reloadGrid so that no `filters` are passed to the server or show up in the GUI search box..

??

Answer (score 16):

You could use the following method:

```
function clearSearchOptions(){
    $("#list").jqGrid('setGridParam', { search: false, postData: { "filters": ""} }).trigger("reloadGrid");
}
```

But as Oleg pointed out, you will have to use the `recreateFilter:true` option in your jqgrid definition if you want the jqgrid search box to be cleared as well.

Comment: thanks, it worked for me:
i was unable to SET data in Subgrid, so i wrote

$("#Subgrid").jqGrid('setGridParam', { search: false, postData: { "filters": "" } });
    $("#Subgrid").setGridParam({ 'data': SubgridData }).trigger('reloadGrid', [{ page: 1 }]);

Comment: @Jimbo I don't think so reloadGrid is mandatory, For me its worked without triggering reloadGrid. Anyway Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 6):

To reset filters you can modify the `postData` parameter of jqGrid directly. You can access it with `$("#list").jqGrid('getGridParam','postData')` or `$("#list")[0].p.postData`. If a filter is set, the properties of the `postData` look like following:

```
_search      true           Boolean
nd           1286296925096  Number
page         1              Number
rows         10             Number
searchField  "id"           String
searchOper   "lt"           String
searchString "5"            String
sidx         "id"           String
sord         "desc"         String
```

To reset the properties you can do following

```
var postdata = $("#list").jqGrid('getGridParam','postData');
postdata._search = false;
postdata.searchField = "";
postdata.searchOper = "";
postdata.searchString = "";
```

If you use [Advanced Searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:advanced_searching) instead of [Single Searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:singe_searching) you should clear `filters` property instead of `searchField`, `searchOper` and `searchString`.

At the end you can call `$("#list").trigger("reloadGrid",[{page:1}]);` to reload the grid contain starting with the page number 1.

Comment: Thanks Oleg - but this doesn't appear to reset the grid's search UI.  That is the prior search criteria still show up when you click the search button in the nav bar.  I'd like to clear these out.

Comment: @Marcus: You asked how to reset jqGrid search options. So I understood that you opened Search dialog set options and then close the search dialog. The search options stay saved in the jqGrid. So I answered how th reset the options. What you then mean? By the way do you use `recreateFilter:true` option?

Comment: We don't use the `recreateFilter` option..  if we manually set postdata, the search data stays saved in the grid - how do you remove the search from the grid so the gui doesn't show any search options selected?

Comment: @Marcus: Could you explain what scenario you mean? Why do you decide that "the search data stays saved in the grid"? What do you mean? How one can reproduce your problem and which behavior exactly you want to have in jqGrid? In general there are search filter in the grid (as a part of postData) and there are a search dialog which will be hide or show. If you use `recreateFilter:true` option the dialog will be always new created instead of showing previously created hide dialog.

Comment: We have our search icon on the nav.  Users can click this button, search on multiple fields - all this works great.  We have another filter option outside of the grid control.  If users select another type of filter, we change the grid url and call reloadGrid.  But when we call reloadGrid the filter options that the user selected with the grid search are still present.  What is the best way to clear out the grid search criteria?

Comment: @Marcus: It is exactly the scenario which I mean as I wrote my answer. If the code from my answer not work then try `var sdata={searchField:"",searchOper:"",searchString:""}; $.extend($("#list")[0].p.postData,sdata); $("#list")[0].p.search=false;`

Comment: Tried both - couldn't get either to work - search GUI still has prior selections in place.  As I'm using the advanced search I modified your last example slightly to use `var sdata={filters:""};`

Comment: @Marcus: I can repeat only once. You should post a full code example then I'll try to modify it so that it will work.

Comment: @Oleg: I was really happy to see the `recreateFilter` option on jqgrid. I also have an external jqgrid filter and wanted jqgrid's search button to reflect what the external filter was filtering. It works the first time jqgrid's search is clicked only :( then if you change the external filter and click jqgrid's search button again, it shows the old filter...

Comment: @Marcus: I found that using recreateFilter: true and Oleg's solution of resetting search params above or even using Mark's answer below (except I use `$(".ui-icon-refresh").trigger("click");`) works great. The jqgrid search panel resets itself too :)

Comment: @Jimbo: Hi! In my opinion the values `recreateFilter:true` and `recreateForm:true` for the form editing should be default settings of jqGrid. Without the settings one can has strange effects and spend many time in debugging. By the way my other old answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974324/jqgrid-using-multiple-methods-to-filter-data/3979490#3979490 and the corresponding demo example http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CheckboxesWithVerticalHeaders1.htm could be probably interesting for you.

Answer (score 3):

To click the "reset" button try:

```
$(".ui-reset").click();
```

Comment: Will try that - my post might be slightly misleading..  What I'm trying to do is clear the search options and call `trigger("reloadGrid")`.  Your suggestion might work..  though would prefer to not literally call `click`..   would like to call a `clearSearchOptions()` method then call `trigger("reloadGrid")`

Answer (score 2):

The only way I could get it right - and I'm sure its not the right way is as follows:

```
$("#grid").jqGrid('setGridParam', { postData: { filters: null} });
$("#gs_ColName1").val("");
$("#gs_ColName2").val("");
```

where ColNameX are the names of your columns

Comment: ideed! Thank you! I combined your last two lines, to clean the search boxes and the first, but additionally i triggered reload!

Answer (score 2):

It will reset all search options

```
$('input[id*="gs_"]').val("");
```

Comment: Making a simple change to `$(':input[id*="gs_"]').val("");` will find all form elements, which includes select boxes.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#resetFilterOptions").click(function(){
        $('input[id*="gs_"]').val("");
        $('select[id*="gs_"]').val("ALL");
        $("#list").jqGrid('setGridParam', { search: false, postData: { "filters": ""} }).trigger("reloadGrid");
        });
```

This one works Rest Search options and Reload the JQGrid

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#search").filterGrid("#list", {
       gridModel: false,
       enableSearch: true,
       filterbutton: 'search_button',
       enableClear:true,
      filterModel: [{
           label: 'First Name',
           name: 'search',
           stype: 'text'
       });
```

Write `enableClear:true` in your `filterGrid`

Answer (score 0):

use only

$("td#refresh_navGrid").click();

Answer (score 0):

I added external refresh button to solve this.

**jgrid.jsp**

```
<sj:submit id="grid_refreshbutton" value=" Refresh" button="true"/>
```

**jgrid.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
jQuery("#grid_refreshbutton").click(function(){
    var postData = $("#gridtable").jqGrid('getGridParam','postData');
    $("#gridtable").jqGrid('setGridParam',{search:false});    
        $.extend(postData, { filters: "" });

        for (k in postData) {
            if (k == "_search")
                { postData._search = false;}
            else if ($.inArray(k, ["nd", "sidx", "rows", "sord", "page", "filters"]) < 0) {
                    delete postData[k];
                   ("#gs_" + $.jgrid.jqID(k), $("#gridtable").get(0).grid.hDiv).val("");
            }
        }
               $("#gridtable").trigger("reloadGrid", [{ page: 1}]);
```

});

Thanks/Regards,
Khine lae